# Probability for class in xgboost

Tags: probability, classification, binary-data, boosting

I'm using xgboost for a problem where the outcome is binary but I am only **interested in the correct probability of a sample to be in class 1.**

My current approach is to use the XGBClassifier in Python with objective binary:logistic, use predict_proba method and take that output as a probability for class 1.

I that methodology correct in the sense that I get actual probability values for a sample to be in class 1?

Comment: Yes.  It's an *estimated* probability, so the phrase "correct probability" is a little off, but in spirit, yes.

Comment: This seems on-topic to me, it's basically asking if the output from a logistic gradient boosting classifier can be interpreted as the estimated probability of class 1.  The fact that the user refers to a specific classifier is unfortunate but that's not an essential part of the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`predict_proba` [yields estimated probabilities that a sample is in class 1](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/91).

Note that the writer of this comment is the author of `xgboost`, so this is the definitive answer on the subject.

Comment: Just to add to this: I found a nice blog entry on http://www.svds.com/classifiers2/  explaining in more details about estimator scores and probabilities.